# Background acrylic brush not working in WinUI app on Uno

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, winui

I am following Microsoft's docs about adding the acrylic effect to a component in XAML. My app is an UNO app, which essentially should just be a normal WinUI app on windows platforms. I have this in my XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Dynamo.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Dynamo"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"    
    Background="{ThemeResource AcrylicBackgroundFillColorDefaultBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello, universe" Margin="20" FontSize="30" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Yet the page does not display the acrylic effect. Is there something i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it after several hours. Will post the solution here incase anyone needs this: You can use this to add mica and acrylic for cross platform apps in UNO:
r
In the root of your uno project, create a file : SystemBackground.cs. Fill it with this:

```
#if WINDOWS
using Microsoft.UI.Composition.SystemBackdrops;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; // For DllImport
using WinRT; // required to support Window.As<ICompositionSupportsSystemBackdrop>()

public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    WindowsSystemDispatcherQueueHelper m_wsdqHelper; // See below for implementation.
    MicaController m_backdropController;
    SystemBackdropConfiguration m_configurationSource;

    public MainWindow()
    {
    //    this.InitializeComponent();

        TrySetSystemBackdrop();
    }

    bool TrySetSystemBackdrop()
    {
        if (Microsoft.UI.Composition.SystemBackdrops.MicaController.IsSupported())
        {
            m_wsdqHelper = new WindowsSystemDispatcherQueueHelper();
            m_wsdqHelper.EnsureWindowsSystemDispatcherQueueController();

            // Create the policy object.
            m_configurationSource = new SystemBackdropConfiguration();
            this.Activated += Window_Activated;
            this.Closed += Window_Closed;
            //((FrameworkElement)this.Content).ActualThemeChanged += Window_ThemeChanged;

            // Initial configuration state.
            m_configurationSource.IsInputActive = true;
            SetConfigurationSourceTheme();

            m_backdropController = new Microsoft.UI.Composition.SystemBackdrops.MicaController();

            // Enable the system backdrop.
            // Note: Be sure to have "using WinRT;" to support the Window.As<...>() call.
            m_backdropController.AddSystemBackdropTarget(this.As<Microsoft.UI.Composition.ICompositionSupportsSystemBackdrop>());
            m_backdropController.SetSystemBackdropConfiguration(m_configurationSource);
            return true; // succeeded
        }

        return false; // Mica is not supported on this system
    }

    private void Window_Activated(object sender, WindowActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        m_configurationSource.IsInputActive = args.WindowActivationState != WindowActivationState.Deactivated;
    }

    private void Window_Closed(object sender, WindowEventArgs args)
    {
        // Make sure any Mica/Acrylic controller is disposed
        // so it doesn't try to use this closed window.
        if (m_backdropController != null)
        {
            m_backdropController.Dispose();
            m_backdropController = null;
        }
        this.Activated -= Window_Activated;
        m_configurationSource = null;
    }

    private void Window_ThemeChanged(FrameworkElement sender, object args)
    {
        if (m_configurationSource != null)
        {
            SetConfigurationSourceTheme();
        }
    }

    private void SetConfigurationSourceTheme()
    {
     
         m_configurationSource.Theme = Microsoft.UI.Composition.SystemBackdrops.SystemBackdropTheme.Dark; 
        
    }
}

class WindowsSystemDispatcherQueueHelper
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct DispatcherQueueOptions
    {
        internal int dwSize;
        internal int threadType;
        internal int apartmentType;
    }

    [DllImport("CoreMessaging.dll")]
    private static extern int CreateDispatcherQueueController([In] DispatcherQueueOptions options, [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] ref object dispatcherQueueController);

    object m_dispatcherQueueController = null;
    public void EnsureWindowsSystemDispatcherQueueController()
    {
        if (Windows.System.DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread() != null)
        {
            // one already exists, so we'll just use it.
            return;
        }

        if (m_dispatcherQueueController == null)
        {
            DispatcherQueueOptions options;
            options.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DispatcherQueueOptions));
            options.threadType = 2;    // DQTYPE_THREAD_CURRENT
            options.apartmentType = 2; // DQTAT_COM_STA

            CreateDispatcherQueueController(options, ref m_dispatcherQueueController);
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

And finally in your app.cs, change the following code accordingly:

```
#if NET6_0_OR_GREATER && WINDOWS && !HAS_UNO
        MainWindow = new MainWindow();
        MainWindow.Activate();
```

And that's it. A mica window should now be opened. If you'd rather use acrylic, then you may replace all MicaController classes to DesktopAcrylicController in the SystemBackground.cs. Make sure your Page component in your xaml does not have a background property or it will override the backdrops